Connect to deployed anchor program using @coral-xyz/anchor library?
I got some information about blinks actions, it's great I understand how it works, but now I want to use blink actions to connect to the program I deployed on devnet. I wonder if connecting to idl is correct, I have only worked through idl locally
I hope everyone can help. Thank you everyone for your replies

I am not very familiar with blinks, but one option is to copy the IDL file to your project, instantiate it and use it like a normal anchor program
let program = new Program<ProgramName>(
    programNameIDL as unknown as SoundworkList,
    provider
);

await program.methods......, 
// use the `.transaction()` method to convert to a transaction instead of calling it using rpc()

A more tedious way, would be to write your own SDK from scratch or look into using generator tools like codama

great! thank you so much

hello Jimii,  I want to use anchor idl in the back end, can you help me with a specific example? Thank you for your help

https://github.com/SoundWorkLabs/soundwork-sdk
